# process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process error while running sql files using command prompt

Tags: sql, batch-file, command-line, processbuilder

I want to run a set of sql files and created a batch file that will run all the sql files using sqlcmd command

```
for /R %%a IN (*.sql) do sqlcmd -H dbip:dbport-U dbname -P dbpwd -d dbname -i "%%~fa" >> results.txt
```

This batch file will iterate and run all the sql file(including some 4000kb file).

I wrote a java program to execute this batch file using ProcessBuilder

```
    String batchFilePath = "D:/path1/path2";
    List<String> command = new ArrayList<String>();
    command.add("cmd.exe");
    command.add("/C");
    command.add("start");
    command.add("mybatch.bat");

    ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
    processBuilder.directory(new File(batchFilePath));
    Process process = processBuilder.start();
    InputStream inputStream = process.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
    }
inputStream.close();
reader.close();
```

The batch is started to execute all sql file but after some time, separate command prompt is opened and throws an error like **process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process** for all remaining sql file. After throwing this error message in new window, the previous window again started to execute the remaining sql file.

Can anyone help me to understand why that error message is getting displayed and how to solve this problem ? or Is there any other better approach instead of using ProcessBuilder ?

Comment: If you run mybatch.bat from the command prompt (i.e., not using the java program to start it), does the same thing happen?

Comment: No. It is working properly from command prompt.. I missed to close the streams in Java and included that too and tried. But no use if I run using java. I am not able to figure out the issue.

Comment: i also tried with process.waitFor() but still getting this error. This issue is occurring while having many sql files. this is not occurring for less number of files

Comment: I think this is occurring because the output from all of the processes is going to one file, and the more that are running the more likely there will be contention writing to that file

Comment: Remove the `>> results.txt` and see if that resolves the problem. If it does then you'll have to find a different logging scheme.

Comment: When the error is returned, does it state what file cannot be accessed?  I'm not sure as your comments might be interpreted as the error is reporting that the .sql files cannot be accessed, but that doesn't make much sense.  If it doesn't tell you what file, use Process Monitor (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to capture file activity while it is running and it will show you what file the error is occurring on.

Comment: Another thing that might be helpful to know--how many .sql files are there?  If there are several dozen and you have numerous sqlcmd.exe running at the same time, it might be better to set it up so that only 10 or 20 run at one time.

Comment: @Tony. yes it contains more number of .sql files. I will try to remove the result file and solve this. If it still exist, i will split up the sql file and run it.. Thanks for your help.